# ExtJS - How can I rollback selection to old selected record in Grid?

Tags: select, extjs, grid, selection, rollback

It is using grid of ExtJS.
I would like to do some validation before record in grid change to another record.

Below is my sample code:

```
xtype: 'grid',
bind: {
    store:'{xxStore}'
},
columns: [
    {
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
    }
],
listeners:{
    beforeselect: 'onBeforeSelect',
    select: 'onSelect'
}
```

In Controller, sample code is as below:

```
onBeforeSelect: function(grid) {
    // whether can select or not
    if (this.getSettingType() === 'global') {
        return false;
    }
},

onSelect: async function(grid, itemRecord) {
    if (!(await checkUserAction())) {
        // TODO: how to rollback to old selected record here or onBeforeSelect?
    }
},

checkUserAction: function() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let me = this;

        Ext.Msg.show({
            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
            title: 'Confirm Discard Changes',
            msg: 'Do you want to discard changes?',
            callback: function(button) {
                if (button == 'yes') {
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

How to perform it?

---

Supplement the selection flow:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the model (records) you do a reject.  On the store you do a rejectChanges this will call reject on each record.

EDIT: - each record (instance of Ext.data.Model or descendant) is either a new record (phantom = true) an existing record, an existing record that has been modified (dirty = true) or an existing record that has been erased (erased = true).  Any existing record may have fields that have been changed since it was originally loaded or last committed.

When a record is inserted into the store if the idPropery is set with a value then it is considered an existing record if not then it is a new record (phantom = true) that has not yet been committed and therefore a "phantom". Same with record that you execute the erase() method.  It is to be deleted. The record is still in the store just set to erased=true.  When you execute the sync() method on the store phantom records are saved in the database, modified records has is changes saved and erased records are removed from the database.  How all these changes are done is based on the proxy of the model.... after the sync is called the phantom records are no longer phantoms but existing records.  erased records are removed from the store and modified records are no longer considered "dirty" or modified.

If you do a rejectChanges on the store prior to the sync() then the store will go back to how it was after the last sync() or load().  Phantom records will be removed, erased records will to back to not being erased and modified records will have all changes set back to how they were prior to the change.

So in your case, set the idProperty (in the model) to the primary key of the record and make sure it has a value when you insert the records into the store.  Then when you do a rejectChanges on the store it will go back to the way it was prior to the changes.  You can run commitChanges() on the store that will make set all records to unmodified, not phantom and not erased.

FYI: If you don't pass an id property sencha will assign a unique key to the record but still make it a phantom (phantom = true)

Comment: Hi @mcg1103, tested that grid.getSelectionModel() does not have reject function. Thus, when I called grid.getStore().rejectChanges(), all the records in grid are gone. May you share some coding for reference? thanks.

Comment: My guess is that each record (Ext.data.Model) was set with phantom = true.  This means that it is a new record (not yet saved in the database/remote) so when your reject on the store it will remove these records because it thinks they were added and not saved.  You have to set an idProperty on the model and when you insert the records it has to have a value.  When you load records from a database they have a primary key therefore the idProperty will have a value.

Comment: @DaiKeung - I edited my answer to clear some stuff up regarding the store.

Comment: Hi @mcg1103, thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I added idProperties to try but still not okay. I even tried to commitChanges after inserted data to store. I supplemented the expected flow for reference. Please advise, thanks.